# Android latest YouTube update -- In which Location YouTube videos will store when i download in offline

Tags: android, youtube

Recently i got YouTube update. In that they given offline storage option. I want to know where these offline videos are saving. I searched all my phone and SD card, but i am not able to find out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The location of the video will be .

Internal storage or (External storage )/Android/data/com.google.android.youtube/files/Offline/(system generated folder name)/streams.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

On Android, you can use the "Share" button on the YouTube app to share the video with a file manager app. The file manager app can then save the video to your phone's gallery.

https://youtube.com/shorts/UkBBWB7z864?feature=share